# event.keyCode not giving keycode of up and down key after ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, keycode

I have an ajax request for auto completing a text field.The results are appended to a div. Now what I need to do is navigate through the results by up and down arrow.But I m not getting the keycode of the up and down from the keydown jquery function.Any help is appreciated.The code i m using is

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

   $('body').on('keydown','#searchid',function(e) {
      console.log(e.keyCode);
      alert(e.keyCode);
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {        
         $('#autoCompleteResult > .auto_container table').next().focus();
         return false;
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {        
         $('#autoCompleteResult > .auto_container table').prev().focus();
         return false;
      }else{
         s = $(".searchBoxContent").val();
         setTimeout(function() { 
            if($('#searchid').val() == s){ 
               $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "/ajax_search_autocomplete.php",
                  data: 'search=' + s,
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(data) {
                     if(data){
                        //jQuery("#autoCompleteResult").html(data).show();     
                        jQuery("#autoCompleteResult").html(data).fadeIn();  
                        //Js_Keyboard_Selection();

                        $('#searchid').blur();
                        $('.auto_container table:first').focus();
                        //clearTimeout(typingTimer);
                     }else{
                        jQuery("#autoCompleteResult").fadeOut(); 
                     }
                  }
               })
             }
        }, 1000);
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: You're missing a `;` after the ajax function

Comment: R U getting key code HERE ? `console.log(e.keyCode);`

Comment: no ! after ajax loaded the content the console, keyup, keydown nothing works.Any idea??

Answer (score 1):

Some browser don't use `keyCode` but `which`

Try this:

```
var pressedKey = e.keyCode || e.which;
```